# form controls stay filled out after redirect to same form Angular

Tags: angular

I've got a sign-in form `http://localhost:4200/sign-in` Suppose I fill it out and then I decide to go to `http://localhost:4200/` Home page. In my `AppRouting.ts` I've got an AuthGuard that prevents **not** authenticated users to enter Home page and are redirected to Sign-In page. After been redirected back the form stays filled out as before. So Angular somehow calculated that we will get back to the same page and therefore there is no reason to refresh the page? Because if I leave to any other page and return to sign-in form it **is** cleared.

Can I override this behavior? 
I also tried to make `resetForm()` via `@ViewChild(NgForm) userSignInForm: NgForm;`
 in the `ngOnInit`  method but no luck - I think because this method is never called as no actual component reload happens. Ideas?

**AppRouting:**

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [

{ path: '', component: MainComponent, data: { title: 'main' }, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] } 
];
```

**AuthGuardService:**

```
    @Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private router: Router,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        console.log('authGuard fired');

        return this.authService.isUserAuthenticated().pipe(
            map((isUserAuthenticated: boolean) => {
                if (!isUserAuthenticated) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/sign-in'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
                }
                return isUserAuthenticated;
            })
        );

    }
}
```

**HTML (Form):**

```
  <div class="container">


  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userSignInForm)" #userSignInForm="ngForm" class="userSignInContainer">
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-title>Sign-in</mat-card-title>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="email" type="email" [email]="true" [(ngModel)]="loginData.Email" name="Email" required>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="password" placeholder="password" [(ngModel)]="loginData.Password" name="Password" required>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-error *ngIf="!loginOrPassValid">{{errorMessage}}</mat-error>

      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!userSignInForm.valid">sign-in</button>
      </mat-card-actions>

    </mat-card>
  </form>


</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just discovered a behavior of Angular: a component doesn't get destroyed and recreated if, changing the url, it's still needed.

For example, imagine you have a component `PersonalInfoComponent` which shows the personal information of a user according to an id specified in the url. If you watch the information of user with id *14* visiting `/user/14` and then you move to `/user/15`, the component won't be destroyed and recreated for performance reasons, and you must use the `ActivatedRoute` Observable in order to check if the url changed.

What happens here is very similar. Let me first explain the difference between server-side routing e client-side routing, so it's more clear the reason why this trick is possible.

In **server-side routing**, the content of a page changes as consequence of a HTTP request. The browser doesn't know what the content of that page will be and can't make any forecast about it.

In **client-side routing**, the views change as a consequence of clicks, and the url is updated **after** the new content is showed. There is no server requests involved and since Angular knows exactly what will be the destination, can also avoid refreshing and updating the address bar if it's not needed. For example, if you navigate from `/` to `/first-page`, and `/first-page` contains code that redirects to `/second-page`, then the framework can decide to skip the intermediate step, and only go from `/` to `/second-page`.

This is what's happening. You go from `/sing-in` to `/` which redirects to `/sign-in`. So you never moved from your page.

How to override this behavior? You can force a link to behave server-side in place of client-side.

Just use `<a href="/">..</a>` in place of `<a routerLink="/">..</a>`

Comment: thank you for your explanation! I've posted below sort of a workaround that I've just implemented - it works.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. @Cristian Traìna explained why the form is never refreshed. In my case I don't want to use `<a href="/">..</a>` to force a reload, but I just used a `Subject` to trigger a `formReload`.

**Solution:**

**AuthService:**

in AuthService I added a

`public resetSignInFormOnRedirect = new Subject();`

then in

**AuthGuardService:**

```
canActivate(){
...
this.router.navigate(['/sign-in'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
this.authService.resetSignInFormOnRedirect.next();
...
}
```

**Sign-In component:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.resetSignInFormOnRedirect.subscribe(
          () => {
            this.userSignInForm.resetForm();
          }
        );
}
```